# For a sound on/off toggle, when should I play click button sound effect?

Tags: toggle, sound

For example, suppose my app has some sound effects when click some buttons, and I have a sound toggle button, which clicks to turn on sound, and clicks again to turn off sound. My question is, when should I play the click button sound effect?

1. sound on -> sound off
2. sound off -> sound on

which case should I play the click button sound effect?

Comment: Can you give a little more information about the scenario to help us give a more helpful answer? For example, I am wondering if all the other buttons (that don't start sound) also have this click sound when you press them? What else does the app do other than play sounds that you can turn on and off?

Answer (score 2):

I would implement this function like this:

Default behaviour should be `sound off` or when you use an user profile as user has set this option.

1. When sound is `off` and user clicks on sound toggle button then sound should be played.
2. When sound is `on` and user turns off the sound it should not be played.